# Leiningen third-party plugin - how to debug?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have `:plugin [lein-cljfmt "0.6.4"]` listed in my `project.clj` and I was trying to find a way to understand better the input and the output of a few functions that are called via `lein cljfmt check /tmp/foo-app`.

**Is there any simple way to do that?**

Basically even adding smth like `(println "input arg1" arg1)` to those functions would be enough. If I can patch those functions from a running REPL(like I can do with any other non-plugin dependency) - this is even better.

Comment: you can always use it as a dependency in your project, rather then `:plugin`, and manually call the [check](https://github.com/weavejester/cljfmt/blob/master/cljfmt/src/cljfmt/main.clj#L104) function instead of `lein cljfmt check`. Since it is just a normal clojure project, it won't be anything special about using it programmatically this way.

Comment: the only problem is that `check` calls `system/exit` afterwards, but you can easily suppress that.

Comment: Mind blown! What an elegant workaround!  @leetwinski if you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll gladly accept it. Thank you